# pandas srt.lower() not working on dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, lowercase, kaggle

I'm working with the Titanic dataset available from Kaggle. I have it in a dataframe and i want to change the case of the "sex" column to lowercase. I'm using the following code

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('titanic.csv')
print dfFull['sex'].unique()
df.sex.str.lower()

#check if it worked
print df['sex'].unique()
```

and also trying

`df['sex'].str.lower()`

but when I run `df['sex'].unique()` I get three unique values `[male, female, Female]`.

Why does my code not lower the case of the strings and save it back to the dataframe so i get `[male, female]` of from the `.unique` method?

Comment: Virtually all pandas operations return a copy, you need to assign the result of the function to something or to itself in order for the result to persist

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`str.lower()` does not modify the existing column.  It just returns a new Series with the lowercase transform applied.  If you want to overwrite the original column, you need to assign the result back to it:

```
df['sex'] = df.sex.str.lower()
```